# Raggedleft paragraph in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to typeset a table of two columns, where each column
consists of paragraphs and the paragraphs in the right hand column are
set raggedleft. Here is a minimal example of the code I thought would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{p{50mm}>{\raggedleft}p{50mm}}
  \lorem&\lorem\\
  \lorem&\lorem
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, that produces the error message

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate

l.7   \lorem&
     \lorem
?
```

and the output is not at all what I expected either.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I have to admit, I never got comfortable using LaTeX's tabular environment (other than in rather trivial cases). With plain TeX's \halign I know what I am doing, and I can consistently get the result I want. However, people keep telling me that using plain TeX constructs in LaTeX will get me in trouble.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `\halign` a TeX primitive, not a plain-tex macro? As such, it pretty much *has to be* the way latex constructs tables (that is, the tables themselves, not captions and tablecounters etc.)

Comment: @morbusg: Yes, ´\halign` is indeed a primitive. But primitives are frowned upon as much as plain macros. I have certainly been told to stay away from `\hbox` (another primitive). IIRC, the rationale had to do with colour commands, so if I don't change colours inside the `\hbox`, I should be reasonably safe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to restore `\\` for use in `tabular` after inserting switches like `\raggedleft` in the last column. See the [array](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
    \lorem&\lorem\\
    \lorem&\lorem
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, that did it. But seriously, some more user oriented documenation would have been nice. `\arraybackslash` is described on page 18 of a 31 page manual, in the midst of a description of the package implementation. Nobody is likely to find it unless they want to learn how the array package is implemented. Oh well.

Comment: Nearly every modern PDF viewer offers a search function. So it should not be difficult to find that.

Comment: Except the documentation mentioned only `\raggedright`, not `\raggedleft`. (If I had only used the interactive search, I would have found it.)

Answer (score 25):

> Is there a better way?

I would say yes. I suggest to use `\RaggedLeft` instead: there's no `\arraybackslash` fix required and the justification is better, regarding that there's hyphenation within p columns.

**Explanation:**

For a better illustration, let's reduce the p column width. Here's the `\raggedleft` way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{p{30mm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{30mm}}
  \lorem&\lorem
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now we change:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
...
  \begin{tabular}{p{30mm}>{\RaggedLeft}p{30mm}}
```

[image]

It's not so extremely ragged because now hyphenation is supported, just like in the p cell on the left.

Further notes:

- The content of p cells is fully justified. This may cause undesired gaps between words and does not match the ragged way on the right side. A `\RaggedRight` for the left p cell could be a good and consistent idea.
- Especially in narrow columns additionally inserting `\hspace{0pt}` ensures proper hyphenaton. Otherwise, TeX would not hyphenate the first word of the box.

Since a new column type makes all easier, my choice would be

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

and in the body text I'd just write

```
\begin{tabular}{L{30mm}R{30mm}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \raggedleft\arraybackslash in the last column of the table. For example this is a part of a function that creates a ticked box in the last column (rightest empty box in that case)

```
\raggedleft\arraybackslash\ifnum#2[3]=0{\emptyTick}\else{\crossedTick}\fi\\
```

[image]

Here the full code example [repo](https://bitbucket.org/latexer/betriebsmittelpruefprotokoll/src/master/betriebsmittelpruefprotokoll.tex)