# array package: problem with >{declarations} in preamble: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables

I have a document that uses both the longtable and the array package. At first I ascribed the problem to an interaction of both. After testing, it seems array is the only culprit.

Here's a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.4\textwidth}}
1 & a \\
2 & b \\
3 & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It produces the error

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/raggedleft-paragraph-in-a-table?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I used search but wasn't able to locate a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\raggedright` changes `\\` so it no longer means *new row*. When adding `\raggedright` to the last column, use `\raggedright\arraybackslash` that restores the tabular meaning of `\\`