# raggedright table paragraph with array package gives me error message, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: arrays

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright}p{0.45\textwidth}}
        foo   & bar  \\
        one   & two  \\
        three & four \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.6         one   &
                    two  \\
?
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong but I just can't figure it out. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You need to add `\arraybackslash` after `\raggedright`. (I'm pretty sure similar questions have been asked before, if I can't find one I can add an answer.)

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/raggedleft-paragraph-in-a-table?rq=1

Comment: Somehow I missed those two. I was looking at a third one but for some reason completely missed the `\arraybackslash` thing. I also looked in the `array` package documentation but missed it there as well for some reason...

Comment: I was looking at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52247/298 I don't understand if that works though but that is beside the point now I guess...