# How to use gathered inside tabular without causing excess space in nearby columns?

Tags: tables, cases, white-space, gather

I would like the circuit layout and the mathematical equations of a certain circuit to be side by side with relevant captions. I use a table for this, since I might also add some information in the future. Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % I use 2 cm to save space.
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array} % For fixed length columns in tabular environments
    \usepackage{ragged2e} % To better align fixed length columns to the left. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7375
\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Common Source Stage with Resistive Load}\ \\
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{commonSourceWithRLoad} &
        $\begin{gathered}
            I_D = \begin{cases}
                \mu_n C_\text{ox}\frac{W}{L} \left[ \left(V_\text{GS} - V_{\rm th}\right)V_\text{DS} - \frac{{V_\text{DS}}^2}{2} \right] (1 + \lambda V_{DS}) & , \text{triode}\\
                \frac{1}{2}\mu_n C_\text{ox}\frac{W}{L}\left(V_\text{GS} - V_\text{th}\right)^2(1 + \lambda V_{DS}) & , \text{saturation}\\
                I_\text{0} e^\frac{V_\text{GS}}{nV_\text{T}} & , \text{inversion}
            \end{cases}\\
            V_{DS}=V_{DD}-R_D I_D\\
            V_{GS} = V_{in}
        \end{gathered}$ \\
        Circuit Diagram & Mathematical Model
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result has some excess whitespace, how can I get rid of it? The picture itself has almost no whitespace, so it isn't the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Is the following closer to the expected output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Ckb.png If so, give adding `valign=c` to the optional argument of `\includegraphics` a try (requires `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks, Mensch. Yes, the result in the image was what I was looking for. It solved it, thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comment.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I figured out an alternative solution using `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % I use 2 cm to save space.
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray} % version 2021P or newer
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Common Source Stage with Resistive Load}\    \\

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} c  X[b, c] @{}},
                 rowsep=3pt}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{commonSourceWithRLoad} 
    &   \SetCell[c=1]{l}
        {$I_D = \begin{dcases*}
            \mu_n C_\text{ox}\frac{W}{L} \left[ \left(V_\text{GS} - V_{\rm th}\right)V_\text{DS} - \frac{{V_\text{DS}}^2}{2} \right] (1 + \lambda V_{DS}) 
                & ,     triode  \\
                \frac{1}{2}\mu_n C_\text{ox}\frac{W}{L}\left(V_\text{GS} - V_\text{th}\right)^2(1 + \lambda V_{DS}) & , \text{saturation}\\
            I_\text{0} e^\frac{V_\text{GS}}{nV_\text{T}} 
                    & , inversion   
                \end{dcases*} $ \\[2ex]
            $V_{DS}=V_{DD}-R_D I_D, \qquad  V_{GS} = V_{in}$ \\   
        }  \\
Circuit Diagram 
    &   Mathematical Model
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]